# Disable smooth scroll Firefox-Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, marionette

I want to disable Smooth Scrolling of any page for testing purposes for firefox, I want the exact same behavior as this --disable-smooth-scrolling=true chrome's argument. With that argument, chrome basically does the scrollIntoView() instant, instead of auto.

Why do I want to disable it? Well because selenium-w3c is not waiting long enough for the animation to finish, causing ElementNotInteractableException or ClickInterceptedException.

I tried disabling a bunch of preferences, including all the settings that have "smoothScroll" in it, but no luck so far. No preference I change seems to affect firefox in any way. I have a lot of workarounds for this, but the best solution would be to disable it entirely.

Edit:

RESOLVED, I created a simple add on to override scroll-behavior from CSS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any issue report to Selenium? Could you share a link, please?

Comment: Not yet, since I think this is not an issue with Selenium. My workaround was modify firefox code to always do "scrollIntoView" instant. And that worked perfectly.

Comment: I ended up creating a simple Add On to override scroll-behavior from CSS, and that is working perfectly.